# GRUB broken after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I had an Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 dual boot system with Grub2. After my recent upgrade to free Windows 10. GRUB is broken, it gave me the 
`grub rescue>` prompt.

Reading on internet I figured I had to change prefix and root for GRUB to work correctly, and it did, but it reverted back every time it booted.

I am not a techie so to fix things instead of meddling with changing `/etc/grub.d` etc., I used a boot repair USB key. It changed something and now I  get

```
error symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color' not found
```

and I also can't find `normal.mod`. The link is pasted that was generated by the grub-repair USB key. Help is much appreciated.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15547887/

Comment: As per your pastebin contents 'A disk read error occurred BOOTMGR is compressed Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart' and 'Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda2/efi/.../grub*.efi file!'. Seems like disk issues. Please check the disk first.

Comment: Lenovo uses a hidden ESP for its boot into recovery which looks like sda3. Your ESP is sda2. But it looks like Ubuntu/grub is installed to sda3, not sda2? Did you move boot flag from sda2 to sda3 at some point, because Windows also shows two entries in UEFI, one sda2 & one sda3? I might try reinstalling grub. It should auto install to ESP - efi system partition.

Answer (score 0):

I can make no promises that this will work, but you might want to try my [rEFInd boot manager:](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)

1. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R image of rEFInd from [its downloads page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
2. Prepare a boot medium from the image you download.
3. Boot to the rEFInd boot medium. Its main menu should appear, showing at least one option for each of Windows and Ubuntu.
4. Try the various boot options. With any luck, at least one will work for both OSes.
5. If you can boot both your OSes, boot to Ubuntu. If not, stop.
6. Install the rEFInd PPA or Debian package.
7. Reboot.

With any luck, rEFInd will appear as your default boot program. Note that this procedure is risk-free up until step #6; until then, you will have made no changes to your hard disk configuration.